# access to staorage account from event hub

Tags: spring, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-storage-account

Hi I am trying to receive the message from event hub .Below is the appyaml config I have done in java spring code :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      eventhubs:
        connection-string:  ${EVENT_HUB_CONN:Endpoint=}
        namespace: ${AZURE_EVENTHUBS_NAMESPACE:}
        processor:
          checkpoint-store:
            account-name: ${AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME:}
            account-key: ${STORAGE_ACC_KEY:}
            container-name: ${AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME:ccapiresiliencyservice}
    stream:
      bindings:
        consume-in-0:
          destination: ${AZURE_EVENTHUB_NAME:}
          group: ${AZURE_EVENTHUB_CONSUMER_GROUP:}
      eventhubs:
        bindings:
          consume-in-0:
            consumer:
              checkpoint:
                mode: MANUAL
      poller:
        initial-delay: 0
        fixed-delay: 1000
    function:
      definition: consume;
```

I have created event hub and storage account in azure and everything is working .

But as soon as I enable virtual network in storage account I start receiving error in the application .
[image]

how should I enable access to my storage account from event hub from application now .
I have tried assigning identity and roles but nothing seems to work as of now .

Answer (score 0):

> How should I enable access to my storage account from an event hub in my application?

You can access the storage account from an event hub with enabled selected networks through Azure Virtual Machine.

You need to create a virtual machine and add your public IP address to your storage account like this:

**Portal:**
[image]

Now, you can use the same configuration file with Java Spring code in the Azure Virtual Machine:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      eventhubs:
        connection-string:  ${EVENT_HUB_CONN:Endpoint=}
        namespace: ${AZURE_EVENTHUBS_NAMESPACE:}
        processor:
          checkpoint-store:
            account-name: ${AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME:}
            account-key: ${STORAGE_ACC_KEY:}
            container-name: ${AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME:ccapiresiliencyservice}
    stream:
      bindings:
        consume-in-0:
          destination: ${AZURE_EVENTHUB_NAME:}
          group: ${AZURE_EVENTHUB_CONSUMER_GROUP:}
      eventhubs:
        bindings:
          consume-in-0:
            consumer:
              checkpoint:
                mode: MANUAL
      poller:
        initial-delay: 0
        fixed-delay: 1000
    function:
      definition: consume;
```

I tried with a sample [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send?tabs=connection-string,roles-azure-portal#create-a-python-script-to-receive-events) code to receive the message from the event hub.

**Output:**

```
Received the event: "First event" from the partition with ID: "0"
Received the event: "Second event" from the partition with ID: "0"
Received the event: "Third event" from the partition with ID: "0"
```

**Reference:**
[Tutorial: Connect to a storage account using an Azure Private Endpoint - Azure Private Link | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal?tabs=dynamic-ip)